# why value passed at mViewPager.setCurrentItem(value) is incremented or decremented in getItem(int value) method of FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

I used `NagivationDrawer` along with `ViewPager` for my app. When the user select a item in the drawer, the view pager will set the fragment accordingly.

In MainActivity class

```
....
@Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

        Log.d("POSITION", "=======================================");
        Log.d("POSITION ItemSelected", position +"");


        if(mViewPager != null){
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

        }

    }
......
```

My ViewPagerAdapter class is

```
public class LessonPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public LessonPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {

        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new LessonFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        Log.d("POSITION PagerAdapter", position +"");
        args.putInt(LessonFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 7;
    }
}
```

I found out that the value of `position` I pass when calling `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position)` from `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position)` method  is different(incremented or decremented) from the value of `position` I get in `getItem(int position)` method of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

```
11-01 12:31:59.706    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION﹕ =======================================
11-01 12:31:59.706    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION ItemSelected﹕ 1
11-01 12:31:59.706    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION PagerAdapter﹕ 2
11-01 12:32:11.089    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION﹕ =======================================
11-01 12:32:11.089    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION ItemSelected﹕ 2
11-01 12:32:11.090    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION PagerAdapter﹕ 3
11-01 12:32:18.586    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION﹕ =======================================
11-01 12:32:18.586    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION ItemSelected﹕ 3
11-01 12:32:18.586    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION PagerAdapter﹕ 4
11-01 12:32:29.474    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION﹕ =======================================
11-01 12:32:29.474    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION ItemSelected﹕ 4
11-01 12:32:29.475    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION PagerAdapter﹕ 5
11-01 12:32:35.476    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION﹕ =======================================
11-01 12:32:35.477    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION ItemSelected﹕ 5
11-01 12:32:35.477    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION PagerAdapter﹕ 6
11-01 12:32:43.704    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION﹕ =======================================
11-01 12:32:43.704    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION ItemSelected﹕ 6
11-01 12:32:51.287    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION﹕ =======================================
11-01 12:32:51.287    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION ItemSelected﹕ 5
11-01 12:32:51.287    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION PagerAdapter﹕ 4
11-01 12:33:00.529    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION﹕ =======================================
11-01 12:33:00.530    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION ItemSelected﹕ 4
11-01 12:33:00.530    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION PagerAdapter﹕ 3
11-01 12:33:09.084    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION﹕ =======================================
11-01 12:33:09.084    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION ItemSelected﹕ 3
11-01 12:33:09.084    8913-8913/com.example.khaino.drawerandswipedemo D/POSITION PagerAdapter﹕ 2
```

Can anyone tell me the reason? What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your app working correctly? In a viewPager, not only the current page is loaded, but also the left and right pages, to make the scrolling look seamless. So getItem() is called to preload the next page, your log is totally correct.

You can also use viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int) to set how many pages on each side you want to preload. Default and minimum value is 1.

Comment: Thanks..now I know why value of `position` in `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position)` method and `getItem(int position)` method are different...